# PortType operation input name missing in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, wsdl2java

I have a WSDL where portType-operation-input-**name** is missing.Everything else is fine.I am using WSDL2JAVA from Ant task using CXF.

```
    <operation name="Sym">
        <input  message="tns:SymRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:SymResponse"/>
        <fault message="tns:WSException" name="WSException"/>
    </operation>
```

It throws exception while generating java classes.If I add name attribute , it works. As per WSDL specs name attribute is not required for input parameter then why does it complain.

Comment: Caused by {http://.....}[portType:SymPortType][operation:Sym][output:SymResponse] not exist.
     [java] file:Sym.wsdl:[189,4] 
     [java]  Caused by {http://....1}[portType:SymPortType][operation:Sym][input:SymRequest] not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a name.  Might be optional from WSDL's perspective, but my feeling is that CXF needs that name when creating a method / class.

Try adding a name and searching for that name in the resultant .java files.  That should shine some light on how and why, when using CXF, 'name' is not optional.